# Navigation and search in Java

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jtextfield

I am performing a project in Eclipse. I have my navigation button which is working well. However, I have also a `JTable` in my form to perform search and I can display the record from`Jtable` to my `Jtextfields`. The problem is that after I performed a search and I click on any navigation buttons it says "no more record".

This is my code for searching:

```
txtsearch = new JTextField();
txtsearch.setBounds(723, 85, 150, 25);
add(txtsearch);
txtsearch.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter(){
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e){
        String Query3 = "Select * from customer where CustCompanyName = ?";
        try {
            stt = con.prepareStatement(Query3);
            stt.setString(1, txtsearch.getText());
            rs = stt.executeQuery();
            table2.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));                 

        } catch (SQLException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }               
    }
});
```

and this one is my code for displaying into textfields:

```
table2.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter(){
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e){

        try {
            int Row = table2.getSelectedRow();
            String ccode = (table2.getModel().getValueAt(Row, 0).toString());
            String Query4 = "Select * from customer where CustomerCode = '"+ccode+"'";
            stt = con.prepareStatement(Query4);
            rs=stt.executeQuery();
            while(rs.next()) {
                txtcode.setText(rs.getString("CustomerCode"));
                txtcompname.setText(rs.getString("CustCompanyName"));
                txtaddress.setText(rs.getString("CustAddress"));
                txtpnumber.setText(rs.getString("CustPhoneNumber"));                        
            }                   
        } catch (SQLException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: 'it says'...what says? Nothing in the current code you posted defines the phrase "no more record", nor are there 'buttons' defined in your code.

Comment: i posted only the code of searching and displaying in textfield .. in my eclipse i have declared everything.. and "no more records" is found in my navigation button:

Comment: @Aalm : Have you seen my answer?

Answer (score 0):

Your program logic is not implemented properly.

#### Using the same "rs" multiple times.

here table2 resultset may have 100 rows.

```
   String Query3 = "Select * from customer where CustCompanyName = ?";
    try {
     stt = con.prepareStatement(Query3);
     stt.setString(1, txtsearch.getText());
rs = stt.executeQuery();
     table2.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));
```

and here table2 resultset may have only 1 rows.

```
     String ccode = (table2.getModel().getValueAt(Row, 0).toString());
     String Query4 = "Select * from customer where CustomerCode = '"+ccode+"'";
     stt = con.prepareStatement(Query4);
rs = stt.executeQuery();
```

If you change the resultset `rs`, all rows assigned to the table2, suddenly disappear.
Assuming `resultset` has now only `one row`.
Navigational button are superfluous.

**If you no longer wish to appear the message "no more record".**

- disable all navigation buttons like `next` and `previous`, if only one row is present.

---

#### Your `while` makes no sense

```
while(rs.next()){
```

> If the result has many rows

why to fill all the `JTextField()`  over and over again ?
Only the last row/CustomerCode will be in `txtcode` !!
One Solution use `rs.next()` with a `if` instead of a `while`.

```
if (rs.next()){
        txtcode.setText(rs.getString("CustomerCode"));
        txtcompname.setText(rs.getString("CustCompanyName"));
        txtaddress.setText(rs.getString("CustAddress"));
        txtpnumber.setText(rs.getString("CustPhoneNumber"));
}
```

---

In your Code to fill the Textfields there is only one event.

```
table2.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter(){
   public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e){
           ....
```

You must have also a event if the dataset cursor changed through a navigation button like `next or prior` .

---

**Solution**

- use 2 resultset
- rsCustCompany
- rsCustomerCode

---

```
    String Query3 = "Select * from customer where CustCompanyName = ?";
    try {
    stt = con.prepareStatement(Query3);
    stt.setString(1, txtsearch.getText());
 rsCustCompany = stt.executeQuery();
    table2.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rsCustCompany));
```

---

```
    String ccode = (table2.getModel().getValueAt(Row, 0).toString());
    String Query4 = "Select * from customer where CustomerCode = '"+ccode+"'";
    stt = con.prepareStatement(Query4);
 rsCustomerCode = stt.executeQuery();
```